# How to encode 3 integer values into an uint16_t using bitwise operations?

Tags: c++11, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I want to store 3 unsigned integer values into an `uint16_t` variable by doing bitwise operations and read them back using bitwise operations. Following is my program to do that:

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

uint16_t Write(unsigned int iVal1, unsigned int iVal2, unsigned int iVal3) {
    // iVal1 should go into the first 8 bits [iVal1 value ranges from 0 to 173]
    // iVal2 should go into the 6 bits after that [iVal2 value ranges from 0 to 63]
    // iVal3 should go into the 2 bits after that [iVal3 value ranges from 0 to 3]
    // Is the below way of writing the bits correct?
    return (static_cast<uint16_t>(iVal1)<<8) + (static_cast<uint16_t>(iVal2)<<6) + (static_cast<uint16_t>(iVal3)<<2);
}

unsigned int ReadVal1(const uint16_t theNumber) {
    // ival1 is the first 8 bits
    uint16_t check1 = 255;
    return (theNumber>>8)&check1;
}

unsigned int ReadVal2(const uint16_t theNumber) {
    // ival2 is the 6 bits after that
    uint16_t check2 = 63;
    return (theNumber>>3)&check2;
}

unsigned int ReadVal3(const uint16_t theNumber) {
    // ival3 is the last 2 bits
    uint16_t check3 = 3;
    return (theNumber>>1)&check3;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Main started" << std::endl;

    unsigned int iVal1 = 191;
    unsigned int iVal2 = 28;
    unsigned int iVal3 = 3;

    const uint16_t theNumber = Write(iVal1, iVal2, iVal3);

    std::cout << "The first 8 bits contain the number: " << ReadVal1(theNumber) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Then after 6 bits contain the number: " << ReadVal2(theNumber) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Then after 2 bits contain the number: " << ReadVal3(theNumber) << std::endl;
}
```

In above program following are the ranges of the 3 unsigned integers that need to be encoded.

```
`iVal1` ranges from `0 to 173`. So its well within 8 bits.
`iVal2` ranges from `0 to 63`. So its well within 6 bits.
`iVal3` ranges from `0 to 3`. So its well within 2 bits.
```

**Question:**
I think that the way I am writing the values inside the function `Write` is wrong. What is the correct way?

*Primarily, I am looking for a good explanation* of how the encoding using bitwise operation works especially in the context of the goal of my program above.

I believe that my way of reading the values in the functions `ReadVal1`, `ReadVal2` and `ReadVal3` is correct. I have figured out the trick of how to read back the values which seems easy. But, I could not well understand the logic of how to encode the values correctly using bitwise operations.

**C++ compiler:**
I am using a **C++11** compiler

Comment: I updated the question to show the ranges of the 3 unsigned integers that need to be encoded in

Comment: Your `write` is wrong, and your `read` is wrong too. The number of bits you need to shift is not the size of the integer you want to read and write, it is the combined size of all the remaining integers (because you are shifting in order to make room for *those*). The last integer should not be shifted at all. The number of bits you shift-right on `read` should be exactly the same as the number of bits you shift-left on `write`. Where you got `>>3` and `>>1` is a mystery.

Comment: Ah, my read is wrong as well! That is really good information. So the number of bits I want to shift is the  combined size of all the remaining integers? Can you please explain with explain with an answer? Thanks a million for taking a look

Comment: Just correcting my program with some kind of explanation should be good enough for me to understand develop upon that.

Comment: I don't understand the bit shifting completely well. I am trying to :-(

Comment: Well I think the explanation is good enough. Try replacing shift values with 8, 2 and 0. We shift the *second* integer left by 2 bits because we need those 2 bits to fit the *third* integer. When reading, we shift back by the same 2 bits.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out the program based on your explanation. So the second integer would have occupied the remaining 8 bits normally. But we shifted it by 2 bits to make space for the last. If we would have wanted to make space for 3 bits then we would have left shifted by 3 bits during writing. And the last just occupies the remaining bits by default provided that it is within the remaining bits. Did I understand this correct @n.'pronouns'm. ?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Feel free to post an answer if you want and I can accept it. I have corrected the program with your explanation. `ReadVal3` is like this by the way - `uint16_t check3 = 3; return theNumber&check3;`

Comment: If you don't need a portable layout, an alternative is to use bit-fields.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I might have not understood you 100% because of me not being pro in this area. The bit layout is important for me. Like bit number 0 to 7 should contain the first value, bit number 8 to 13 should contain second and so on. This is important for me while encoding the numbers. Other than that if you meant any other layout then that is trivial for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of bits to shift an integer should not depend on the size of the integer being shifted, but on the size of all the integers that come *after it* (to the right). Here's some ASCII art to illustrate the principle:

```
                                +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                                ‖i1 |i1 |i1 |i1 |i1 |i1 |i1 |i1 ‖ 8 bit
                                ‖ 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 ‖
                                +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                                 _______________________________/
                                /                     
                                |       +---+---+---+---+---+---+
                                |       ‖i2 |i2 |i2 |i2 |i2 |i2 ‖ 6 bit
                                |       ‖ 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 ‖
                                |       +---+---+---+---+---+---+
                                |                       ________/
                                |                      /
                                |                      |+---+---+
                                |                      |‖i3 |i3 ‖ 2 bit
                                |                      |‖ 1 | 0 ‖
                                |                      |+---+---+
                                |                      \        |
                                |<<(6+2)                |<<2    |<<0
                                v                       v       v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
‖ F | E | D | C | B | A | 9 | 8 ‖ 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 ‖ 1 | 0 ‖
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
‖i1 |i1 |i1 |i1 |i1 |i1 |i1 |i1 ‖i2 |i2 |i2 |i2 |i2 |i2 ‖i3 |i3 ‖
‖ 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 ‖ 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 ‖ 1 | 0 ‖
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for such a well illustrated explanation. The line quoted in the answer cleared my mind on how this stuff works.  ---- > "The number of bits to shift an integer should not depend on the size of the integer being shifted, but on the size of all the integers that come after it (to the right)". Not I get it!

Comment: How do you make these ascii illustrations ?

Comment: @Tanishq-Banyal by hand in a text editor